# Add a class to wordpress submit_button

Tags: php, css, wordpress, submit-button

Is there a way to add a "class" to this line to make it adhere to the .button styling in my CSS stylesheet?

```
<?php submit_button(__('Update Profile')); ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: can you show the html what this code will produce?

Comment: `submit_button` isn't native PHP. Where are you using this code?

Comment: Why dont you style the button in HTML file?

Comment: @HebleV She/he needs to use the `submit_button` in Wordpress

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`submit_button()` is a core admin utility function. It's one of the many elements making up the WordPress admin theme and it's supposed **not to be styled**, so it will gracefully change when WP core developers decide to change the admin theme.

However, if you really want to style that particular button, here's what I suggest: add a custom attribute to your button, called `data-style`:

```
<?php 
$attributes = array( 'data-style' => 'custom' );
submit_button ( 'Update Profile', 'primary', 'submit', true, $attributes );
?>
```

And, in your CSS you can now style your button with:

```
[data-style="custom"] {
     /* style your button here */
}
```

---

UPDATE: [Trix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35248110/1891677) made me take a closer look at the [function referrence](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/submit_button) and realized (`$type`) can safely be used to add custom classes to any WP admin button. It's as simple as:

```
submit_button ( 'Update Profile', 'custom-class' );
```

Note that (according to the function reference) your button will still have the default `button` class. This should work:

```
.button.custom-class {
     /* styles here */
}
```

---

UPDATE 2:
I've done some more testing and apparently, the function works as advertised. The actual output of

```
submit_button(__('Update Stuff'), "custom-class");
```

was:

```
<p class="submit">
    <input type="submit" 
           name="submit" 
           id="submit" 
           class="button custom-class" 
           value="Update Stuff">
</p>
```

**Most of the rules applying to the buttons in WP admin area are prefixed with `.wp-core-ui`.** In this case, they come from `.wp-core-ui .button` or `.wp-core-ui .button:hover`. So the following selectors should work:

```
.wp-core-ui .button.custom-class {
     /* normal state rules here */
}
.wp-core-ui .button.custom-class:hover {
     /* hover state rules here */
}
.wp-core-ui .button.custom-class:focus,
.wp-core-ui .button-custom-class:active {
     /* active/focus state rules here */
}
```

For example, adding this to the dashboard CSS changed the appearance of my button, without affecting other buttons:

```
.wp-core-ui .button.custom-class {
    background-color: #272727;
    border-color: #666;
    color: #ddd;
}
.wp-core-ui .button.custom-class:hover {
    background: #212121;
    border-color: #666;
    color: white;
}
```

Made it look like this: [image: update_stuff_button]

**Please note that `.custom-class` rules will be overridden by any rules set with `.wp-core-ui .button`** (the default selector for buttons in WP Admin).

Comment: Nice solution.  This works, and doesn't require a class.

Comment: This is nice, but it is not an answer to the question.

Comment: The reason he wanted to add a class was to style the button, without giving it an unique identifire. I guess I provided the means, since adding classes to this type of core element is not straight forward.

Comment: That may be true, but consider future references to this question. as the question title, does not describe your comment

Comment: Okay, so @AndreiGheorghiu your method worked...sort of...I added your code and it enlarged the button about twice as high as it was, making it about 2px taller than the other ones... it did that without adding any type of CSS styling.... when I try to add styling nothing changes... even with "!important" added after to overwrite anything else.... strange

Comment: I finally got. It worked oddly enough by removing the .button. So just having this allowed me to style it correctly. .custom-class {
     /* styles here */
}

Answer (score 3):

You may simply ,add your class like this:

```
submit_button( __('Update Profile'), 'my-custom-class' );
```

Comment: You're right, `$type` accepts custom classes. This is the correct way to add classes to WP admin buttons.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php submit_button(__('Update Profile', 'button')); ?>
```

This should work :) You can view the parameters of submit_button() here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/submit_button/

As you can see, the default class should be "primary". I dont know if Wordpress requires that, otherwise I guess you could just try:

```
<?php submit_button(__('Update Profile', 'button primary')); ?>
```

Comment: "$type
(string) (Optional) The type and CSS class(es) of the button. Core values include 'primary', 'secondary', 'delete'. Default 'primary'
Default value: 'primary'"

Comment: Please read here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/submit_button

"Note: $type can be a single value, or a space separated list of values, or an array of values. The values determine the HTML classes of the button."

I know what you're saying - primary should already be setting both "primary-button" and "button" as the classes, but i answered the question on how to add custom classes to a submit_button function ;)

Comment: "any other type value 'foo' makes the class 'foo'"